# Posting JSON data to Team Foundation Server 2018

Tags: json, api, http-post, postman

I am trying from POSTMAN with http-post to open new user story using JSON. In header is Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

File looks like:

```
{
  "id":33560,
  "rev":2,
  "fields":{
    "System.AreaPath":"EJ2TFS",
    "System.TeamProject":"EJ2TFS",
    "System.IterationPath":"EJ2TFS\\Iteration 1",
    "System.WorkItemType":"User Story",
    "System.State":"New",
    "System.Reason":"New",
    "System.AssignedTo":"User, User <firm\\user>",
    "System.Title":"Postman_POST",
    "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority":2,
    "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea":"Business",
    "System.History":"Comment"
  }
}
```

Error:

```
   {
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "You must pass a valid patch document in the body of the request.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssPropertyValidationException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common",
    "typeKey": "VssPropertyValidationException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3000
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a work item ([Rest Api Work Items - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)) use the url and body below:

> POST
>
> http(s)://your_server:port/tfs/DefaultCollection/EJ2TFS/_apis/wit/workitems/$user story?api-version=4.0

Body

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Postman_POST"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.AssignedTo",
    "from": null,
    "value": "User, User <firm\\user>"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.IterationPath",
    "from": null,
    "value": "EJ2TFS\\Iteration 1"
  }    
]
```